# Gnuplot wouldn't reset (GIF)

Tags: animation, plot, gnuplot, gif

It is supposed to reset and make an animation.
I have tried all the suggestions from other previous posts, but I still have this result.
[image]

my datei.dat has 4 columns with an empty line seperating each block.

```
set autoscale
set datafile seperator ","
plot "datei.dat" index (i) u 1:2 t '1:2' with linespoints ,\
   "datei.dat" index (i) u 1:3 t '1:3' with linespoints ,\
   "datei.dat" index (i) u 1:4 t '1:4' with linespoints 
replot
pause 1
i = i + 1
if(i<N) reread
```

animate.plt

```
reset
set term gif animate
set terminal gif animate delay 50
set output "plotalive.gif"
N = int(STATS_blocks)
i = 0
load "animate.plt"
set output
```

loop.plt

Comment: And what do you expect to be reset at which stage? Please be more specific.

Comment: to make animated gifs, you need `libgd` to support it. From `help gif`: `The animate option is available only if your local gd library supports
 the creation of animated gifs`.
Try `set term gif animate; set out "test.gif"; do for [n=0:10] {plot sin(x*n) w l}; set out`

Comment: @bibi I have checked and confirmed that I already have libgd installed. And your script is working on my computer too. Still, I couldn't apply it to my work.

Answer (score 1):

If n is the size of blocks you should use the every.
Index is used to separate datasets (two blank lines).

Here is a what might be done avoiding the reread (some change might be done):

```
set terminal dummy
plot "datei.dat"
N = int(STATS_blocks)

set terminal gif animate delay 50
set output "plotalive.gif"

set autoscale
set datafile seperator ","

do for [i=0:N] {
plot "datei.dat" u 1:2 every ::i::i t '1:2' with linespoints ,\
   "" u 1:3 every ::i::i t '1:3' with linespoints ,\
   "" u 1:4 every ::i::i t '1:4' with linespoints 
}
set output
```